# Zego Uikit Prebuilt Call Package Use And Application Not Run

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  **Execution failed for task ':is_lock_screen2:parseDebugLocalResources'.**

Could not resolve all files for configuration

```
:is_lock_screen2:androidApis.
 Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,
 org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
 Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\baps\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
 C:\Users\baps\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar
```

Compile SDK Version 34,
Min Sdk Version 21

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.